# What part of speech is this "to be grown"?

Tags: to-infinitive

The original sentence is

> The plant itself is the only variety of orchid to be grown on a commercial scale.

I only want to know the function or the **role** of *to be grown* here.
Is it the complement? like part of an infinitive clause? I'm no expert but I still want to know the answer~

Comment: *It's the only one **to be grown** here = ...the only one **which / that is grown** here = ...the only one **grown** here*. I don't know whether they all count as "relative clauses", but so far as I'm concerned they're all equivalent.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks, does "to be grown" have any extra meaning or, is it just a different way of saying "it is the only one grown here.."

Comment: "to be grown on a commercial scale" is a non finite infinitive clause, and not a phrase. POS is assigned to a phrase or a lexical word, but never to a clause. POS is different from role or function. The non finite subordinate clause functions as a (post) modifier in the Noun Phrase structure, realised by the head noun - *orchid*. The concerned Noun Phrase is *the only variety of orchid to be grown on a commercial scale"*. However "on a commercial scale" seems to me an Adjunct, and I think, an obligatory adjunct.

Comment: @Angyang No, it's not a complement, but an infinitival relative clause modifying "variety".

Comment: Thank you @BillJ in my previous comment I made a mistake, I now realised it after reading your comment. The head of the NP is *variety* and not *orchid*. But apart from that is my analysis correct? Because I am not very sure about whatever I said in the last sentence of my last comment, it was just my guess work.

Comment: @Man_From_India Strictly speaking the infinitival relative clause is a modifier in (and thus part of) the head nominal "only variety of orchid to be grown on a commercial basis". Yes, the PP "on a commercial scale" is an adjunct (note that all adjuncts are optional).

Comment: @BillJ yes right. All adjuncts are optional. My bad is that I can't edit it. And the head nominal is *only a variety of orchid*, right? But I thought it's modifying only the *variety*.

Comment: @Man_From_India The head nominal is "only variety of orchid to be gown on a commercial basis", in which the head is "only variety of orchid" with the infinitival clause "to be grown on a commercial basis"as modifier within the upper nominal.